# Showing a growing div onmouseover

Tags: html, css

This is my goal:

[image]

Some circular buttons that have an hover state: on mouseover, a black container with some text (with different length) should appear growing from left to right.

I didn't know how to do that. My doubts are about how to set the two different width because it should be from 0 to auto but if it's 0, then mouseover can't work.

Here is my sample code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.hovered-elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 30px; 
  padding-right: 15px
}

.hovered-elem-text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="circle"/>
    </div>
    <div class="hovered-elem">
      <div class="hovered-elem-text-container">
        Lilly Martin
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start. I think it's all pretty self-explanatory. The max-width on the text elements is arbitrary--set it to something that will fit all possible names.

I simplified the markup a bit. You could take it further by making the inner circles pseudo-elements if you like.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 62px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 32px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.circle {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #CD4025;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .circle {
  background-color: #0097A7;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .circle {
  background-color: #FFAC40;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #000;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.item:hover .text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 16px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lilly Martin</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">Philip McDaniel</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">Tom Bombadil</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this CSS transitions and altering the scale of the div while the circle item is hovered. Take a look what I did here:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.hovered-elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 30px; 
  padding-right: 15px;
  scale: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.hovered-elem-text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.item:hover .hovered-elem{
  scale: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="circle"/>
    </div>
    <div class="hovered-elem">
      <div class="hovered-elem-text-container">
        Lilly Martin
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```